# Adobe air android/ios, how to limit captured video length?

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air, ane

I have been searching but have found no information on this. I am working on an app that captures video from the device camera and I would like to limit the length to one minute or less. I have seen the camera API which allows monitoring the status, but even that does not seem to have options for reading the current state (recording or not) Either way the API says to use `cameraUI` API for mobile, and that has no options other than to lock into video rather than stills.

I also found an `ANE` for `iOS` which allows record start/stop functions, so I could use that to make my own record button and implement a timer before triggering stop. but I cannot find an android equivalent.

I am using Flash Professional CS6, not Flex or Flash Builder.

Has anyone done this or have any ideas how to make this happen?

Comment: Are you using media recorder?

Comment: I am not familiar with it. Is that an API or ANE? A quick google search didn't show me anything.. I also should have mentioned I use Flash Pro Cs6, not Flex or Flash Builder.

Comment: I found media recorder. That is an Android API, but I still have yet to find a premade ANE for it, so I guess I will have to factor in making one. Thank you for pointing me toward that. I am still open to a premade option for a camera ANE with ths capability if anyone is aware of a good one out there.

Comment: are you looking for an ANE with simply a start/stop record function or one that has a complete UI?

Comment: Basically start and stop so I can limit the max length of the recording. Ability to max at 720p would be nice too but not necessary. Something for iOS and android would be best but at least android.